# What is an unambiguous term for a square standing on its corner?

Tags: vocabulary, ambiguity

I'm helping write descriptions for a catalogue of Pacific artefacts, and have stumbled upon a problem. A fan is shaped like a square, with a handle coming down from one of the corners. What is the most unambiguous term to best describe this fan:

- rhombus-shaped fan
- square fan
- diamond-shaped fan

Something else?

Comment: 'shaped like a square, with a handle coming down from one of the corners. '

Comment: Square diamond shaped

Comment: Probably "diamond shaped fan" is most suggestive, if no more info is provided, and the exact squareness is not important.  "Square fan" suggests (absent other info) that the handle on one side, rather than at a corner.  If it's necessary to describe it exactly, though, use more words.

Answer (score 3):

Of the three, i'd pick "diamond-shaped".  Diamonds are not always square, but they can be. And baseball diamonds, as well as the diamonds suit in playing cards, are typically portrayed with one corner up, not one side up.

Of course, this would not imply anything as to where the fan handle is attached.  (An illustration would be ideal—but that might not be feasible in your project.)

Comment: I'm conflicted whose answer to accept, since you're right that 'diamond' suggests the shape is standing on a corner, but @Charon is right that 'diamond' could actively imply the shape is _not_ square...

Answer (score 3):

I would not use diamond-shaped because then people might think it's *not* square shaped, when in fact it is. They might infer that it's a 'squashed square' or kite shaped, like either of these:

[image: diamond shape][image]

---

The best description would be ***a square fan, with a handle on one of its corners***.

Comment: Your description is definitely the one to go for, and we will describe it as such in the first instance - we're trying to keep later entries compact, hence the naming issue.

Comment: In that case, because you are looking for the *most* unambiguous term, the answer *must* be *square fan* because that description has zero ambiguity, whereas the other options have some, as my answer outlined.